# Python Driver - webelement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) does not send the enter key

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**webElement**=`.ciscoDnaDcs--widgets-findText-findText_less--inputContainer input`

> ```
> self.type_and_enter(webElement, 'abc')
> ```
>
> **is not able to focus on an element in chrome driver, but works in
>   firefox**

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x106a96c50>
[2] response = {'sessionId': 'adee263e6aa6f12646ca971b268efb93', 'status': 13, 'value': {'message': 'unknown error: cannot focus elem... (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)'}}
```

> **Chrome version:**  `70.0.3538.110`
>
> **ChromeDriver:** `2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189)`

Manually able to find the element and everything is fine, what might be the issue?

The similar question raised here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1572 but it has got closed without any answers. Looking forward to solution on this if some have faced it and overcome

Comment: This is likely a problem related to what element you are sending "return" to, it's probably not an input or textarea element and cannot be focused. Could you show a reproducible example maybe? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - I have element of type `input` only and addressing it like this: `.ciscoDnaDcs--widgets-findText-findText_less--inputContainer input`

Comment: Okay, could it that the element is disabled?

Comment: No, it’s enabled and I can manually search the same from dim and also I can try sending keys using jquery from console. All works, except here

Comment: Got it. Could it be a timing issue? For instance, what would happen if before sending the keys you would, for testing purposes only, put a `time.sleep(5)`? (5 seconds is just a sample, please adjust)

Comment: I am waiting till 30s but no luck

Comment: can you type without the enter?